# this code first time run is work but second time show "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'answer' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$(function() {
  $("#startBtn").hide();
  $(".questionPage").hide();
  $("#navUl a").click(
    function() {
      if ($(this).text() === "Math") {
        redayTest(testHtml);
      }
    });
  let testHtml = [{
      index: 0,
      question: "1+1=?",
      option: [0, 1, 2, 3],
      answer: "2"
    },
    {
      index: 1,
      question: "2+3=?",
      option: [3, 4, 5, 6],
      answer: "5"
    },
    {
      index: 2,
      question: "3+4=?",
      option: [7, 8, 9, 10],
      answer: "7"
    }
  ]

  let change = function(testItem, index) {
    let optionNumber = [0, 1, 2, 3, ];
    let randomNumber = optionNumber.sort(() => .5 - Math.random());

    $(".question").text(testItem[index].question);
    $("#option1").text(testItem[index].option[randomNumber[0]]);
    $("#option2").text(testItem[index].option[randomNumber[1]]);
    $("#option3").text(testItem[index].option[randomNumber[2]]);
    $("#option4").text(testItem[index].option[randomNumber[3]]);
  }

  let changeNumber = [0, 1, 2]
  let randomQuestionCount = 0;
  changeNumber = changeNumber.sort(() => .5 - Math.random());

  let redayTest = function(testItem) {

    $("#startBtn").show()
    $("#startBtn").click(function() {
      $(".questionPage").show();
      change(testItem, changeNumber[0]);
      console.log($("#option4,  #option3,  #option2,  #option1").text());
      console.log("answer = " + testItem[(changeNumber[randomQuestionCount])].answer);
      $(".questionPage button").click(function() {
        QuestionsCheck($(this), testItem);
      })
    })
  }

  let QuestionsCheck = function(option, testItem) {
    if (option.text() === testItem[(changeNumber[randomQuestionCount])].answer) {
      randomQuestionCount++;

      if (randomQuestionCount === changeNumber.length) {
        console.log("done")
        $(".questionPage").hide();
        $("#startBtn").hide();
        $(".question").text("done");
      } else {
        change(testItem, changeNumber[randomQuestionCount]);
        console.log($("#option4,  #option3,  #option2,  #option1").text());
        console.log("answer = " + testItem[(changeNumber[randomQuestionCount])].answer);
      }
    } else {
      option.text("done")
    }
  }









})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul id="navUl">
  <li><a>Math</a></li>
</ul>

<button id="startBtn">check</button>
<p class="question"> </p>
<div class="questionPage">
  <button id="option1">A</button>
  <button id="option2">B</button>
  <button id="option3">C</button>
  <button id="option4">D</button>
</div>
```

this code first time run is work

but second time show "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'answer' of undefined"

i don't understand. because first is work.

other problem i click several times "Math" before click check .

when click check after.

console.log show several times answer and option value.

may above two problem is same error source code ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure your "startup" code is inside the startup event, not the page startup.

Specifically the error is pointing at this code:

```
 testItem[(changeNumber[randomQuestionCount])].answer
```

saying that  `testItem[(changeNumber[randomQuestionCount])]` is `undefined`, so it's likely that `randomQuestionCount` hasn't been reset.

Adding

```
randomQuestionCount = 0;
```

inside startBtn.click will reset the question position and remove your error.

You might like to consider an `init()` function and put this kind of initialisation there (but it's just the same as inside the click event, just clearer what it's doing).  You could, for example, also move `changeNumber = changeNumber.sort(() => .5 - Math.random());` inside the init() so it changes each time.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#startBtn").hide();
  $(".questionPage").hide();
  $("#navUl a").click(
    function() {
      if ($(this).text() === "Math") {
        redayTest(testHtml);
      }
    });
  let testHtml = [{
      index: 0,
      question: "1+1=?",
      option: [0, 1, 2, 3],
      answer: "2"
    },
    {
      index: 1,
      question: "2+3=?",
      option: [3, 4, 5, 6],
      answer: "5"
    },
    {
      index: 2,
      question: "3+4=?",
      option: [7, 8, 9, 10],
      answer: "7"
    }
  ]

  let change = function(testItem, index) {
    let optionNumber = [0, 1, 2, 3, ];
    let randomNumber = optionNumber.sort(() => .5 - Math.random());

    $(".question").text(testItem[index].question);
    $("#option1").text(testItem[index].option[randomNumber[0]]);
    $("#option2").text(testItem[index].option[randomNumber[1]]);
    $("#option3").text(testItem[index].option[randomNumber[2]]);
    $("#option4").text(testItem[index].option[randomNumber[3]]);
  }

  let changeNumber = [0, 1, 2]
  let randomQuestionCount = 0;
  changeNumber = changeNumber.sort(() => .5 - Math.random());

  let redayTest = function(testItem) {

    $("#startBtn").show()
    $("#startBtn").off("click").click(function() {

      // init a new round here
      randomQuestionCount = 0;


      $(".questionPage").show();
      change(testItem, changeNumber[0]);
      console.log($("#option4,  #option3,  #option2,  #option1").text());
      console.log("answer = " + testItem[(changeNumber[randomQuestionCount])].answer);
      $(".questionPage button").click(function() {
        QuestionsCheck($(this), testItem);
      })
    })
  }

  let QuestionsCheck = function(option, testItem) {
    if (option.text() === testItem[(changeNumber[randomQuestionCount])].answer) {
      randomQuestionCount++;

      if (randomQuestionCount === changeNumber.length) {
        console.log("done")
        $(".questionPage").hide();
        $("#startBtn").hide();
        $(".question").text("done");
      } else {
        change(testItem, changeNumber[randomQuestionCount]);
        console.log($("#option4,  #option3,  #option2,  #option1").text());
        console.log("answer = " + testItem[(changeNumber[randomQuestionCount])].answer);
      }
    } else {
      option.text("done")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul id="navUl">
  <li><a>Math</a></li>
</ul>

<button id="startBtn">check</button>
<p class="question"> </p>
<div class="questionPage">
  <button id="option1">A</button>
  <button id="option2">B</button>
  <button id="option3">C</button>
  <button id="option4">D</button>
</div>
```

---

As an extra, it's generally a bad idea to nest event handler declarations.  Your code does:

- when `navUL a` clicked, add a new event handler to startBtn
  so each time you start you get another event handler on startBtn and it runs twice/three-times etc.  In the snippet above I've mitigated this with a `.off("click")` but it's better to declare event handlers at the top level (or at least not within another event handler).

You'll have the same issue with `$(".questionPage button").click`, but I've left that as the issue is around `randomQuestionCount` being reset.

Comment: thank your suggest . help a lot for me learn new code ".off()".